# Session issue when cookies are disabled in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

Whenever cookies are disabled in my browser and then i try to login on login page it unable to create session and so unable to login in system. Then i change the cookie setting to

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" timeout="20" />
```

in my web.config and then try to login Post action of the login function it doesnt call and whenever i input username and password and sumbit it, it call simple login action instead of Post one. What is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't confuse session with authentication. If you are using Forms Authentication a separate cookie will be used to track authenticated users. Here's a [good article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647070.aspx#pagexplained0002_cookielessforms) explaining how to enable cookieless forms authentication. You could set the `cookieless` attribute on the [`<forms>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx).

Comment: im not using form authentication instead i have built my own login mechanism. I just want to login user whenever cookies are disabled in user browser

Answer (score 0):

Quote:

"im not using form authentication instead i have built my own login mechanism. I just want to login user whenever cookies are disabled in user browser"

End Quote

That's the problem with rolling your own login:  you lose all the benefits of using Membership Providers.  You should cast your "own login mechanism" into a custom membership provider so that you can benefit from what ASP.NET provides out of the box.

Writing a custom membership provider is not difficult, and there are loads of articles, samples and blogs on the subject.

4guysfromrolla.com, for example, has a series of articles dedicated to the ASP.NET membership provider.